# Research of latex font

Tags: fonts, typography

Does someone know the font being used in the document below? Looks like it is DejaVuSans but still I can't get the same resul as in the pdf. If someone could help, I would really appreciate it! Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: you have the pdf so the font menu should tell you the font  or use the pdffonts commandline utility to list them. You don't need to guess.

Comment: Latin Modern Sans. https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/lm/